# How to combine files in folder into one file and cut it by indexes given?

Tags: python, file

I need to combine data files into 1 file using indexes in files because the necessary data is between them. And save the data as NumPy array.
Indexes are "Data_start" and "Data_end".
Here is the code I'm working on:

```
import os
import numpy as np

f = open('combined.csv', 'w')                   # create file
filenames = os.listdir('data')                  # data files list in folder "data"
with f as combined:                             # open file 'combined.csv'
    os.chdir('data')                            # change folder to data folder
    for filename in filenames:                  # for each name in file
        with open(filename) as infile:          # read filename in file as 'infile'
          # here is the code to cut the file between [datastart:dataend] indexes ?
            combined.write(infile.read())       # write in 'combined' what you read in file
        combined.write('\n');                   # put 'enter' after

#here is the code to save it as NumPy array?
```

in my case, it saves the file as one long line or as many long lines, but not as a normal CSV.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: the file is saved as one long line because you are using `read()` and `write()`, which read and write the entire file content in one go.
You can use `file_lines = file.readlines()` to read the file contents as lines and store them into a list, and use `writelines()` list of lines after you modify it.